# curl request to docker-compose port hangs in travis-ci

Tags: docker-compose, travis-ci

Our travis builds have started failing and I can't figure out why. Our app runs in docker-compose and then we run cypress to against it. This used to work perfectly. Now the host port for the web server is just unresponsive. I've removed cypress and am just trying to run curl http://localhost:3001 and it just hangs. Here's the travis.yml. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I have tried fiddling for several hours with the docker versions, distros, localhost vs 127.0.0.1, etc  to no avail. All of this works fine locally on my workstation.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "12.19.0"

env:
  - DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=1.25.4

services:
  - docker

sudo: required

# Supposedly this is needed for Cypress to work in Ubuntu 16
# https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/blob/master/basic/.travis.yml
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libgconf-2-4

before_install:
  # upgrade docker compose https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#using-docker-compose
  - sudo rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/${DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION}/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > docker-compose
  - chmod +x docker-compose
  - sudo mv docker-compose /usr/local/bin
  # upgrade docker itself https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#installing-a-newer-docker-version
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install docker-ce
  # Put the .env file in place
  - cp .env.template .env

install:
  # Install node modules (for jest and wait-on) and start up the docker containers
  - cd next
  - npm ci
  - cd ..
  - cd e2e
  - npm ci
  - cd ..

script:
  - docker --version
  - docker-compose --version
  - docker-compose up --build -d
  # Run unit tests
  # - cd next
  # - npm run test
  # Run e2e tests
  # - cd ../e2e
  # - npx cypress verify
  # - CYPRESS_FAIL_FAST=true npx wait-on http://localhost:3001 --timeout 100000 && npx cypress run --config video=false,pageLoadTimeout=100000,screenshotOnRunFailure=false
  - sleep 30
  - curl http://127.0.0.1:3001 --max-time 30
  - docker-compose logs db
  - docker-compose logs express
  - docker-compose logs next

post_script:
 - docker-compose down
```

The logs look like this:

```
The command "docker-compose up --build -d" exited with 0.
30.01s$ sleep 30
The command "sleep 30" exited with 0.
93.02s$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3001 --max-time 30
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
The command "curl http://127.0.0.1:3001 --max-time 30" exited with 28.
```

The docker compose logs show nothing suspicious. It's as if the network wasn't set up correctly and docker is not aware of any requests.

Here is the docker-compose.yml in case it's useful:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mg-postgres
    build: ./postgres
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: 'trust'
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
  express:
    image: mg-server
    build: ./express
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: express:*
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./express
        target: /app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  next:
    image: mg-next
    build: ./next
    depends_on:
      - db
      - express
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./next
        target: /app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    command: ['npm', 'run', 'dev']
```